# Caffe mean file creation without database

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I run caffe using an `image_data_layer` and don't want to create an LMDB or LevelDB for the data, But The [`compute_image_mean`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/tools/compute_image_mean.cpp) tool only works with LMDB/LevelDB databases.

Is there a simple solution for creating a mean file from a list of files (the same format that `image_data_layer` is using)?

Answer (score 2):

You may notice that recent models (e.g., googlenet) do not use a mean file the same size as the input image, but rather a 3-vector representing a mean value per image *channel*. These values are quite "immune" to the specific dataset used (as long as it is large enough and contains "natural images").
So, as long as you are working with natural images you may use the same values as e.g., GoogLenet is using: B=104, G=117, R=123.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that my data is not natural images, and its channels do not correspond to RGB. 
I think I will follow your answer and calculate per channel average of my data using python.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create a LMDB or LevelDB database of the image set.

The complicated solution is to write a tool similar to compute_image_mean, which takes image inputs and do the transformations and find the mean!